# Doubt on Existence of Universal Property from Atiyah

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I've some doubt on **Existence of Universal Property of Tensor Product** :

Let $R$ be commutative ring with $1$ and $M,N,P$ be $R$-modules. Let, $C$ be free $R$-module on $M\times N$ ; i.e. any element of $C$ is of the form $\displaystyle \sum_1^na_i(m,n)$ , where $a_i \in R$ and $(m,n)\in M\times N$. Let $D$ be a submodule of $C$ generated by all elements of $C$ of the following types :
$$(x+x',y)-(x,y)-(x',y)\\(x,y+y')-(x,y)-(x,y')\\(ax,y)-a(x,y)\\(x,ay)-a(x,y)$$

Let , $T=C/D$. Define , $g:M\times N \to T$ by $g(x,y)=x \otimes y $ is bilinear.

*Now any bilinear map $f:M\times N \to P$ extends to a linear map$\bar f:C \to P$* (**HOW ?**)

Then by construction of $D$ we have,  $\bar f (D)=0$. Then $f':T\to P$ defined by$f'(x \otimes y)=f(x,y)$ is well defined *$R$-linear* (**why ?**)

Comment: @user26857 M.F. Atiyah & I.G. Macdonald :Author of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" (available in online) You can see

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the universal property of the free module.

As you say, any element of the free module $C$ has form $\sum_i a_i(m,n)$.
The map $\overline f$ takes this to $\sum_i a_i f(m,n)$.

The map $\overline f$ annihilates all the elements like
$(x,y+y')-(x,y)-(x,y')$ etc., and so annihilates $D$. Therefore
$\overline f:C\to P$ factors through the projection $C\to C/D$.

Comment: I'm not getting your last line.